# NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem set width based on text size

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I have a `UILabel` where I've set all needed constrains, like pin it to the needed sides of other views, set height.

But right now I want to set constraint for width, based on the text length.

How can I make it programatically?

I think I want to something similar to VFL `@”H:|-20-[label1]-10-[label2]-15-“`

so first label should have width based on it's text, and has a distance form the left size equal 20 pt

the second label should have width based on it's text and has a distance from the left side equal 10 pt and 15 form the right side.

[image] as you can see it cut off second label, but I want to have padding like test label at the top.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Normally, you would have no width constraint, and let the label expand as needed.

Comment: If you want it to shrink when less than the length of a full line, simply make the trailing pin >= margin rather than = margin. For multi lines, you normally constrain the width and optionally constrain the height. When both are constrained you have to set the label properties for how to handle too much text: e.g. wrap, truncate start, middle, end, reduce font etc... For multiline you can set the max number of lines in the UILabel or set it to 0 for any number of lines allowed.

Comment: @rdelmar, ok got so I don't need then constraint width, seems it works, but if lenth of the label is too big how can restrict it? I mean something like set max width. I want to have a padding between right side of superview and my label. Like 10 pt padding at the right side. Like In VFL `@”H:|-20-[label1]-10-[label2]-10-“`

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel so as I understood correct from rdelmar comment, I don't need to add constraints for width if I want to have width based on text. I've added comment above as well. Let me update my question.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel, I've updated it

Comment: When you have 2 labels side by side you have to change the content hugging or compression resistance of the one you want to grow at the expense of the other. Try changing the compression resistance of label 2 to 1 less than the value of label 1.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set the label's `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` and set the `numberOfLines` to 0. Give the label a top and leading edge constraint, but nothing more. Now the label will expand its width based on its contents, up to the max layout width, and then will wrap and expand its height instead — automatically.

Comment: how can I calculate this max width? I don't know the width of the label 1, it can be different time to time? thanks for answer!

Comment: Just make up a number. :) Of course you might want to base it on the surrounding situation (e.g. how wide is the superview).

Comment: so I have red superview, and I don't know it size, app stretches it for me with conmtratints I set, but there is no constants like width. So I have left padding for image and have padding between labels, but I don't know a size of first label that is under TEST label to calculate it.

Comment: This works as well if you ignore preferredMaxLayoutWidth and instead set a width constraint using NSLayoutConstraint.

Comment: @Scooter you cannot actually ignore preferredMaxLayoutWidth. It is what does the work. It merely happens that if the preferredMaxLayoutWidth is set to zero, its effective value is the same as the actual constrained width of the label.

Comment: I did not set it, so I guess it defaults to zero then.